# C to Assembly conversion problems

Tags: c, assembly

I'm trying to convert my C code into assembly without using gcc -S function since I want to practice assembly myself. For some reason I can't get my assembly file to match my c code and I can't figure out why. Here is what I've written, the C code is correct but the assembly code doesn't compile. This is sparc assembly btw.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int charCompare( const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2 )
{
    char i = *((char *)ptr1);
    char j = *((char *)ptr2);

    if (i > j)
        return (1);
    if (i < j)
        return (-1);
    return (0);
}
```

Here is the supposedly equivalent assembly code.

```
.global        charCompare      !makes the function globally usable
.section       ".text"

charCompare:
save    %sp, -96, %sp !save caller's window; if different than -96
cmp i1, i2     !compare i1 with i2
bg  returnpos !if i1 is greater than i2 jump to returntrue
cmp i1, i2     !compare i1 with i2
bl returnneg


returnneg:
set -1, %o0
ba end

returnpos:
set 1, %o0
ba end

end:
ret 
restore
```

Comment: well I'm running a makefile for this along with other files and for some reason with the c file is compiles but with the s it gives errors.

Comment: nvm, I screwed up on my makefile, I think it works now that I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command:

```
gcc -S -O0 myfile.c
```

That extra gcc option will turn off all optimizations (like ones that can rearrange your code).

Comment: From the assembly, it doesn't look like any optimization has occurred.

Comment: Did you read the part of the original question that specifically said **without using gcc -S**?

Comment: I was assuming he was using gcc to check his assembly code (hence the "supposedly correct" part). I see what your saying now though.

Comment: I forgot the implement the assembly files into the makefile, now it works I think. If you can't find any problems with it then I think i got it